# Get conflict when creating tables with Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I started practicing with symfony 2. So my question is about this command:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

This is the result of this command execution:

```
CREATE TABLE Article (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, image_id INT NOT NULL, publication TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, date DATETIME NOT NULL, titre VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, auteur VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, contenu LONGTEXT NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_CD8737FA3DA5256D (image_id), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE Image (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, alt VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE Voiture (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, nom VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, modele VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, couleur VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, date_creation DATE NOT NULL, photo LONGTEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE Article ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CD8737FA3DA5256D FOREIGN KEY (image_id) REFERENCES Image (id)
```

This command makes me crazy, it generates not only the related tables but also other tables of another entities!!!

**I removed all my previous databases but still get the same problem.**

I need just **the voiture table**. All the other tables belongs to an other previous database.
How can I stop that??
 this is my entities code:

**car entity:**

```
<?php

namespace Younga\RentBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Car
 */
class Car
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $nombre;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $modele;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $couleur;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $datecreation;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $photo;


public function __construct()
  {
    $this->datecreation         = new \Datetime;
    }




       /**
         * Get id
         *
         * @return integer 
         */
        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }

        /**
         * Set nombre
         *
         * @param integer $nombre
         * @return Car
         */
        public function setNombre($nombre)
        {
            $this->nombre = $nombre;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get nombre
         *
         * @return integer 
         */
        public function getNombre()
        {
            return $this->nombre;
        }

        /**
         * Set nom
         *
         * @param string $nom
         * @return Car
         */
        public function setNom($nom)
        {
            $this->nom = $nom;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get nom
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getNom()
        {
            return $this->nom;
        }

        /**
         * Set modele
         *
         * @param string $modele
         * @return Car
         */
        public function setModele($modele)
        {
            $this->modele = $modele;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get modele
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getModele()
        {
            return $this->modele;
        }

        /**
         * Set couleur
         *
         * @param string $couleur
         * @return Car
         */
        public function setCouleur($couleur)
        {
            $this->couleur = $couleur;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get couleur
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getCouleur()
        {
            return $this->couleur;
        }

        /**
         * Set datecreation
         *
         * @param \DateTime $datecreation
         * @return Car
         */
        public function setDatecreation($datecreation)
        {
            $this->datecreation = $datecreation;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get datecreation
         *
         * @return \DateTime 
         */
        public function getDatecreation()
        {
            return $this->datecreation;
        }

        /**
         * Set photo
         *
         * @param string $photo
         * @return Car
         */
        public function setPhoto($photo)
        {
            $this->photo = $photo;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get photo
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getPhoto()
        {
            return $this->photo;
        }
    }
```

**commentaire entity:**

```
<?php

namespace Younga\RentBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Commentaire
 */

/**
 * @ORM\@ORM\Entity
 * 
 * 
 */

class Commentaire
{



    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Younga\RentBundle\Entity\Voiture")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * 
     */
    private $voiture;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $auteur;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $contenu;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $datecomment;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set auteur
     *
     * @param string $auteur
     * @return Commentaire
     */
    public function setAuteur($auteur)
    {
        $this->auteur = $auteur;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get auteur
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getAuteur()
    {
        return $this->auteur;
    }

    /**
     * Set contenu
     *
     * @param string $contenu
     * @return Commentaire
     */
    public function setContenu($contenu)
    {
        $this->contenu = $contenu;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get contenu
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getContenu()
    {
        return $this->contenu;
    }

    /**
     * Set datecomment
     *
     * @param \DateTime $datecomment
     * @return Commentaire
     */
    public function setDatecomment($datecomment)
    {
        $this->datecomment = $datecomment;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get datecomment
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getDatecomment()
    {
        return $this->datecomment;
    }


      /**
       * @ORM\prePersist
       */
      public function increase()
      {
        $nbCommentaires = $this->getVoiture()->getNbCommentaires();
        $this->getVoiture()->setNbCommentaires($nbCommentaires+1);
      }

      /**
       * @ORM\preRemove
       */
      public function decrease()
      {
        $nbCommentaires = $this->getVoiture()->getNbCommentaires();
        $this->getVoiture()->setNbCommentaires($nbCommentaires-1);
      }
}
```

I need just the related tables to my **current entity**. It call all the previous entity that I created last time.
Thanks in advance and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have annotations in your Entities like:

```
namespace Your\OwnBundle\Entity;

use Whatever\You\Use\Here;

/**
 * Myentity
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="myentity")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Myentity
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="smallint", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    //... more code
{
```

Try to remove the annotations `@ORM\Table(name="myentity")` and `@ORM\Entity`. This way I think that Symfony will not recognize them as Entities to being taken into account.

Hope I helped you, mate!

Comment: What a pity! Well, can you update your first post with your entities code for me to take a look?

Comment: you can see it now with code.(car & commentaire entity)
thanks.

Comment: I think that `Commentaire` Entity is getting updated (or created if doesn't exist) because is related to `Voiture`. Is that correct? From now I'm a bit lost, so I don't know which entities must be updated and which others doesn't.